# bs4 (Beautiful Soup) for Python3 not working in visual studio

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, visual-studio-2017

I am new to Python and I already get an error with the libraries, am running python 3 on visual studio community edition 2017. I already installed anaconda3 64bit with the installation process but the issue is when I call for the bs4 library (BeautifulSoup) it's returns an error telling me that the module does not exist as shown in the picture:

[image: error message]

How can I install it correctly?

Comment: You need to install `bs4`, try using `pip`, from the command line: `pip3 install bs4`

Comment: thank you for your answer, actually i already did that but still not working, it does work in the console and sublime text 3 but visual studio still don't recognize it.

Comment: I cannot understand why someone wouldn't use vs code for python for such task. With vs code, setting the Anaconda environment would be even easier, just select the environment from left bottom task line and use the terminal to run your file/project within that environment.

Answer (score 1):

you need do add it to the virtual environment of your project
**Tools -> Python -> Python Environments**
It will open a sidebar to the right
Click on the "overview" select "packages" then search for "BeautifulSoup4" and click "install"
now it's in your project

Answer (score 0):

You may also need to set the Python Environment on your solution.

Right-click the Python Environments node for a project in Solution Explorer and select Add/Remove Python Environments.

[image: Add/Remove Python Environments]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/managing-python-environments-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2017